# Install MS Outlook 2010 in silent mode using c#

Tags: c#

Am creating a windows application and I want to install Outlook 2010 in silent mode using `C#` code. And what are the arguments we need to pass to it and how pass the KEY for activation as well.

All this has to be done in `C#` (something like below code)

```
     Process process = new Process();   
     process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";   
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";   
     process.Start();   
     process.WaitForExit();
```

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Why don't you just use one of the many tools that will allow you to do this?  Why develop your own application to something that is already possible with installer parameter or tools to create system images?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/148938/office-2010-silent-activation-after-unattended-installation Have a look at this.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with C#, a BAT file is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a config file for Outlook installation as mentioned in the below link,

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/e16af71c-fed4-40da-a886-95e596c3999e(Office.14).aspx#ElementPIDKey

I have passed the config file to the arguments,

```
     Process process = new Process();
     process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\temp\Setup.exe";
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/config \\C:\temp\config.xml";
     process.Start();
     process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run outlook installation with parameter '/?' or '/HELP'. It will be displayed all avaliable command line parameters for installation. Silen mode is in the list